# matplotlib: Unequally spaced ticks / Zero at a specific color

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar

I have been trying to solve a problem for a while now, and neither stackoverflow, nor another website could help me.

I am trying to plot a field (contourf) with a range from -40 to 36 with the colorbar gist_rainbow_r with 52 discrete steps. 
As you can see, the levels are not equally spaced. What I would like is a colorbar with equally spaced ticks (all the levels should be equally spaced), having the color of the discretized 52 gist_rainbow_r colors. Is this at all possible? Here below the code snipplet.

```
    levels = [-40,-30,-20,-15,-12,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36]
    # define the colormap
    cmap = cm.get_cmap('gist_rainbow_r',52)
    # define the bins and normalize
    norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(levels, cmap.N)
    contourplot = map.contourf(xpoints,ypoints,fieldtoplot,range(-40,36),cmap=cmap,norm=norm,spacing='regular')

    ax = plt.gca()  # Gets the current axes
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)  # Lets us move axes around
    cax = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="2%",pad=-0.02,axes_class=maxes.Axes)  #Adds an axis for the colorbar
    F.add_axes(cax)  # Adds the new axis to the figure as the current working axis
    bar = plt.colorbar(contourplot,cax=cax,orientation='horizontal',spacing='regular',extend='both',extendfrac='auto',extendrect='True',format='%1i',ticks=levels, boundaries=levels) # Plots colorbar in new axis 
    bar.update_ticks()
```

Best regards

Martin

Comment: try to pass `levels` to `map.contourf()`, like `map.contourf(..., levels=levels)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Saullo Castro. Still no changes, unfortunately. But this was a good part of the real answer - answered below!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the solution is so easy it is a bit embarrassing to write it here... Sorry bothering the community!

Here we go - this solved my problem:

```
levels = [-40,-30,-20,-15,-12,-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36]
# define the colormap
cmap = cm.get_cmap('gist_rainbow_r',52)
# define the bins and normalize
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(levels, cmap.N)
contourplot = map.contourf(xpoints,ypoints,fieldtoplot,range(-40,36),cmap=cmap,norm=norm,spacing='uniform', levels=levels)

ax = plt.gca()  # Gets the current axes
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)  # Lets us move axes around
cax = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="2%",pad=-0.02,axes_class=maxes.Axes)  #Adds an axis for the colorbar
F.add_axes(cax)  # Adds the new axis to the figure as the current working axis
bar = plt.colorbar(contourplot,cax=cax,orientation='horizontal',spacing='uniform',extend='both',extendfrac='auto',extendrect='True',format='%1i',ticks=levels, boundaries=levels) # Plots colorbar in new axis 
bar.update_ticks()
```

So, to be clear: Set "spacing" to "uniform" (and not equal - by looking at colorbar.py I noticed that this setting did not exist at all) and pass "levels" to the contourf function.

At this point: Thanks @Saullo Castro for partly answering the question!

Cheers

Martin